# Auto open OS X app when specific USB device connected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, usb

I am writing a OS X app and wanted to open the app whenever specific USB device is connected (specially
camera).

As per my research one solution is to make use of launchd to auto open the app when USB is 
connected by creating plist file with specific criteria. I was able to open the app when
any USB device is connected like (iPhone or Pen Drive) but was not able to figure out way to only
open the app when Camera is connected. Below is the plist snapshot that i am using for launchd:

```
<key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.matching</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.device-attach</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bDeviceClass</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>bDeviceSubClass</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>bDeviceProtocol</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
                <key>IOMatchStream</key>
                <true/>
                <key>IOMatchLaunchStream</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>

    </dict>
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any other way to auto open the app without using launchd. I
   have seen the apps those opens  when specific USB device is
   connected like iPhoto and iTunes when iPhone is connected and even
   many custom apps.
2. If there's no other way apart from launchd then
   is it possible to modify the launchd to only open app when camera is
   connected to the system.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know about launchd, although it strikes me as the best way to go about this if you can make it work. The other way you could autolaunch your app is to create a 'Login Item'. This is a Mini App that is running behind the scenes when the user logs in (like Dropbox) and looks after some stuff quietly. (Like uploading files). The downside to these is that the user can turn them off and then you lose your functionality.

Comment: I believe this is handled by ImageCaptureCore. Never used it.

Comment: @PierreBernard, ICCameraDevice of ImageCaptureCore does have a property like `autolaunchApplicationPath` but i am not sure how to use it as it is specific to ICCameraDevice and instance of it will only be available when app is running, where as I want it to work always. @RASS having a mini app in background is also a good idea but i think here I can make use of mix approach like, Launch that mini app when any USB get connected and that mini app then can check if connected device is the device i am interested and then will open the main app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my research and working solution so that other can use if needed.

After my further research it seems like that OS X ImageCapture keeps mapping of devices to the auto open app path in com.apple.ImageCapture2 plist file.

If you run `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.ImageCapture2` on terminal you will get list of something like (it may be empty if none of the app has used auto open feature):

```
"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000004A93AAA" =     {
        ICADeviceTypeKey = ICADeviceTypeCamera;
        autolaunchApplicationPath = "";
    };
    HotPlugActionArray =     (
   );
    HotPlugActionPath = "";
    LastHotPlugActionPath = "";
```

Here HotPlugActionPath is the key and any app path assigned to this key will be opened when connected to system. You can also assign specific app to particular device using persistentID string (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000004A93AAA) and autolaunchApplicationPath. I edited programatically this plist file and assigned my app path here and it works as i was expecting.